# Delete a record if nil is returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, methods

I am making requests to the Facebook API and some of the responses are empty/nil and I am wondering how I can delete these so that when I save them to my model I don't have any nil entries.

```
def formatted_data
  for record in results['data'] do
    attrs = {
             message: record['message'],
             picture: record['picture'],
             link: record['link'],
             object_id: record['object_id'],
             description: record['description'],
             created_time: record['created_time']
            }

         attrs.delete_if { |x| x.nil? }

         Post.where(attrs).first_or_create! do |post|
          post.attributes = attrs
         end
end
```

As you can see I am trying to use the delete_if method but it's not working.

Here's an example of a response that I would like to delete:

```
id: 45
message:
picture: 
link: 
object_id: 
large_image_url: 
description: 
created_time: 2014-04-12 11:38:02.000000000 Z
created_at: 2014-05-01 10:27:00.000000000 Z
updated_at: 2014-05-01 10:27:00.000000000 Z
```

This kind of record is no good to me as it has no message, so maybe I could make the query specify if message.nil ? then delete

### Edit

Been reading the `delete_if` docs and after iceman's comment, I thought this would work but it doesn't, though it seems closer to what I want:

```
attrs = attrs.delete_if {|key, value| key = 'message', value = nil }
```

There are about 25 records returned, of which 5 should be deleted, but after running the above I get one result left in the model:

```
 [#<Post id: 81, message: nil, picture: nil, link: nil, object_id: nil, large_image_url: nil, description: nil, created_time: nil, created_at: "2014-05-01 11:22:40", updated_at: "2014-05-01 11:22:40">]
```

Why are all the rest being deleted, maybe my syntax for accessing the key is incorrect?

Comment: so you have to remove fields : ``message:
picture: 
link: 
object_id: 
large_image_url: 
description: `?

Comment: yes if message = nil then delete the whole record

Answer (score 2):

Since [`#delete_if`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if) passes into block two arguments: the key, and value, try this usage:

```
attrs.delete_if { |k,v| v.nil? }
```

and for [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) you can remove all blank lines, i.e. `nil`, and empty:

```
attrs.delete_if { |k,v| v.blank? }
```

Comment: does that check all of the key/values? as in my case created_time: will always be returned with a value or does this check that if ANY nil value is returned for a record then it will delete

Comment: ok so tried your suggestion, but still getting nil results returned

Comment: @Richlewis can you add output of `p attrs` in the post? Insert of just before `delete_if` line.

Comment: thanks, but that would still leave me with a record wouldn't it as in my example created_time is still populated, yeah getting output for you

Comment: @Richlewis I don't know why created_time is populated, if don't see the dumps `attrs` before delete_if, and after it, and the `@post` after the creation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51811/discussion-between-richlewis-and--)

Comment: Ive added an answer of my own, was wondering if there was a better way of doing this ? maybe you can see what im trying to achieve now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Im adding this in that someone could provide a more efficient way of doing this, maybe before the records get written to the model..But i have managed a solution, albeit a hacky one i would say

I have added this after the creation of the posts

```
delete_if_nil = Post.where(message: nil) 
delete_if_nil.destroy_all
```

Its another query on the db which isnt ideal i guess

Any other suggestions appreciated